# Ruby Madness Downloading same file with Nokogiri, Mechanize and OpenUri to get different information

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize, open-uri

Ok,

I am writing the ubiquitous crawler and have run into some problems. ~Not surprising being a total noob at Ruby.

I use Nokogiri to get the html of a page - find all the links in it that I am interested in and then download the files associated with those links. All is well so far.

However, I don't seem to be able to get the information I need from a single method.

If I use `file = open(Src).read` then file contains the contents of the file - which is great for saving to a database, and for hashing purposes. But it doesn't give me easy access (as far as I have found) to attributes such as filename, size, file type etc.

To get that information I am using Mechanize like this:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
fop = agent.get(Src)
```

Using the head agent.head method I can get the content-type, last-modified date, and content-length. `fop.filename` gives me the filename of course. Now using the `agent.head(Src)["content-type"]` method is, I think re-downloading the information so for the content-type, last-modified and content-length calls - it is downloading the head 3 times. A total waste I would say as file already contains the complete file and fop should provide me with all the other information I need without calling head.

So is there a better way of doing this (from the thumb nail downloader)

```
thumbs.each do |thumb|
  imgSrc = thumb.css('.t_img').first['src']
  file = open(imgSrc).read 
  agent = Mechanize.new
  fop = agent.get(imgSrc)
  p fop
  puts "1 Driver        : prowl.rb" 
  puts "1 Source        : " + pageURL
  puts "1 Title         : " + thumb.css('.t_img').first['alt']
  puts "1 File Source   : " + imgSrc
  puts "1 File Type     : " + agent.head(imgSrc)["content-type"].to_s
  puts "1 File Name     : " + fop.filename
  puts "1 Last Modified : " + agent.head(imgSrc)["last-modified"].to_s
  puts "1 Image Size    : " + agent.head(imgSrc)["content-length"].to_s
  puts "1 MD5           : " + GetMD5(*[file.to_s])
  puts "1 SHA256        : " + GetSha256(*[file.to_s])
end
```

So the question is:

1. How can I optimise my crawler so that I can get all the information I want with the minimum number of requests? and,

Comment: Could you just store agent.head(imgSrc) into a temporary variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
agent = Mechanize.new
thumbs.each do |thumb|
  imgUrl = thumb.css('.t_img').first['src']
  imgTitle = thumb.css('.t_img').first['alt']
  image = agent.get(imgSrc)
  p image
  puts "1 Driver        : prowl.rb"
  puts "1 Source        : " + pageURL
  puts "1 Title         : " + imgTitle
  puts "1 File Source   : " + imgUrl
  puts "1 File Type     : " + image.header['content-type']
  puts "1 File Name     : " + image.filename
  puts "1 Last Modified : " + image.header["last-modified"]
  puts "1 Image Size    : " + image.header["content-length"]
  puts "1 MD5           : " + GetMD5(*[image.content.to_s])
  puts "1 SHA256        : " + GetSha256(*[image.content.to_s])
end
```

Here it is. Reuse the agent, there is no point in creating a new one every time.

Get the page directly from Mechanize, no nead to open and read then pass the content around. All the header information you are looking for is in the `header` attribute of your page.

Comment: However, where is the actual binary data held for the file - the rest of your code is good though.

Comment: I forgot about it, sorry. It is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, nice, neat and efficient.